# How can you enforce a functional dependency in a relation?

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms

If you have a relation R(A,B) with Functional dependency {A → B;} how can you enforce this functional dependency?

a. Make A the key of R
b. Make B the key of R
c. Make {A,B} the key of R
d. No action is needed to enforce the functional dependency

I believe the answer is "a" but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. By creating a primary or unique key on A, we ensure that each value in the domain of A can only appear once, meaning it can only be associated with a single value from B.

If we made B a primary or unique key, we could associate each value in B only once with a value in A, but any value in A could be associated with multiple values in B. If we made {A,B} a primary or unique key, the combination of values in both would have to be unique - any value in A could still be associated with multiple values in B, violating the required FD.

If no action is taken, the result should be the same as making {A,B} a primary or unique key. The reason for this is that the question states we're working with a **relation**, which means rows must necessarily be unique. If we were working with a non-relational table, however, duplicate rows might be allowed, in which case each value in A could still be associated with multiple values in B (except we could do so multiple times).